# sum, range and rangeSum functions

Tags: javascript, array

Forgive me if this is too simple, but I'm a beginner trying to learn and understand. I came across an exercise to create these three basic functions, and this is what I came up with.

Any glaring errors?

---

This program defines three functions:

- `sum(x,y)`
- `range(x,y,step)`
- `rangeSum (start, end)`

`sum` will give you the sum of two numbers.

`range` will give you an array of numbers from `x` to `y`, with an optional step argument that dictates the increment to use when listing the range. If no step is given, the default value is 1.

`rangeSum` will give you the sum of a range of numbers from `start` to `end`.

```
// sum(x,y) takes the sum of two numbers
var sum = function(x,y){
  return x + y;
};
// range(x,y,step) gives an array of the range of x and y, with an optional step argument
var range = function(x, y, step){
    if (step == null) step = 1;
  var arr = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (var i = x; i <= y; i += step)
      arr.push(i);
  } else {
        for (var i = x; i >= y; i += step)
        arr.push(i);
  }
    return arr;
};
// rangeSum(start,end) gives the sum of the range from start to end.          
var rangeSum = function(start,end){
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) 
    arr.push(i);
  return arr.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a + b;   
  });
};
```

Comment: Is the indentation intentional or a messy copy/paste?

Comment: I'm still bad with the indentation, that's me doing that :O I'm going to fix it really quick.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: Still looks a bit wonky to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code is pretty good. No big errors as you fear, there are comments, right indentation, anyone can understand it easily, and... it works !!!

Yet let me suggest a few improvements you could make to make it shine :

For all your functions : use a function declaration : it's easier to use since you can use them anywhere in your code (and not only after the var statement was actually evaluated), and the global namespace pollution is the same anyway.

The `sum()` function just doesn't make sense as it stands : Why one would use `sum(i, 3)` instead of `i+3` ?
It makes sense again with one or both of those features : type checking or accepting any number of arguments.
To type-check or not to is a big debate i won't enter into. I did here since it might be a good way to learn to be cautious about types even in 'typeless' Javascript.
So following code does both type checking and accepting any number of arguments :

```
// returns the sum of its arguments (0 if none). 
// throws if any of them is not a number.
function sum() {
   var result = 0;
   for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
      var thisNumber = arguments[i];
      if ((+thisNumber) !== thisNumber)  {
              throw('Error : argument ' + i + ' of sum is not a number ('+thisNumber + ').');
      }
      result+=thisNumber;
   }
   return result;
}
```

For `range()` : change the arguments name to `start` and `end` makes understanding the function goal easier.
To give `step` a default value, you don't want to test `step` against `null`, but rather against `undefined`.  (it worked because because you used `==`, but notice that by using '==null', you're just testing `is ?? falsy ?`, so the wrong input `0` for step will silently be changed to `1`.).

You might want to check :
       • that `start`, `end`, and `step` (if provided) are meaningful numbers (see above).
        • that `sign(end-start)==sign(step)` so `end` might indeed be reached.
        • that `start-end` is a multiple of `step`. Otherwise you don't get `end` in the range, which i find most annoying.
        • that step is not === 0. In fact the previous check already checked that.

```
// returns an array filled with the range of numbers between start and end,
//   using a optional step that defaults to 1.
// throws if the range cannot be built with the provided arguments.
function range(start,end, step){
    // step defaults to 1
    if (step === undefined) step = 1;
    // type-check start, end, step here if you wish
    // ...
    // checking that step sign allows to reach the end
    if ((end-start)*step<0) {
       throw ('the sign of step does not allow to reach end value');
    }
    // checking that step value allows to reach the end value
    // btw will check that step !==0 also
    var stepCount = (end-start) / step;
    if ( stepCount - Math.floor(stepCount) !==0) { // division has remainder ?
       throw('cannot reach '+end+' starting from '+start+' with the step ' + step);
    }
  // build result array
  var result = [];
  for (var i = start; i != end ; i += step) {  result.push(i);  } 
  return result;
};
```

For `rangeSum` i was surprised to see that you didn't re-use the `range` function you just wrote : In fact you re-wrote a simple version of `range`.
I think only two options are relevant :
  1) re-use `range`, and add an optional `step` argument for free.
  2) if you just want to do a most simple range sum function, go for a `for` loop and sum by yourself.

I choosed (2) :

You might want to check :
       • that `start`, `end` are meaningful numbers (see above).
       • that that end can be reached with a step of 1  <==> that `(start < end)` and `start`, `end` are integers. `( x === 0 | x )`

```
// returns the sum of numbers ranging from start to end(included).          
function rangeSum (start,end){
  var result = 0;
  // you might want to check some things here.
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) { result += i; }
  return result;
};
```

... But in fact, with just a little bit of math, you can write the simple version of `rangeSum` in one line : :-)

```
function rangeSum(start, end) {
  // you might want to check some things here.
  return (end + 1 - start)*( end + start)/2 ;
}
```

Edit :
To allow easier understanding :
1)  I used `Math.floor` to floor the `stepCount`. ( you might forget about the `0 | stepCount` dirty trick for now ).  So when i write `if ( stepCount - Math.floor(stepCount) !==0)` i test if the division has a remainder.
2) `((+thisNumber) !== thisNumber)` *is* a trick to test for `thisNumber` **not** being a number or `NaN`. How ?
a) On the left side, we convert `thisNumber` to a `number`, so since we use `!==`, `thisNumber` has to be from a different type from number => for now it's quite like testing `if (typeof thisNumber === 'number')`.
b) But `NaN` qualifies as a number ( ... ... ), so since `NaN !== NaN`, the expression above does also consider `thisNumber` as wrong if its value is `NaN`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed response. It sure is humbling lol. There's some syntax I don't understand but I'm not sure if it's because I forgot reviewing it, or I haven't came across it yet. I'm going to go back to chapter 1 of Eloquent JavaScript and start to take some detailed notes. These were exercises from chapter 4 and I'm not very happy with how i did :P

Comment: You are welcome. I edited to clarify a few things.

Comment: After going over your code and referring to the MDN for each part I didn't understand, I now have a much better understanding of everything. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

The code looks fine but has a few flaws and can be improved. I didn't solve the flaws and change the code: I've left that as an excercise for you.

In general:

- Why do you use function expressions instead of function declarations?
- I recommend to always use braces, even for single line if statements or for loops. Omitting braces will bite you eventually.
- What happens when the parameters of your functions are not numbers or are undefined?

Your code, with my comments added as review points:

```
// sum(x,y) takes the sum of two numbers
var sum = function(x,y){
    return x + y;
};

// range(x,y,step) gives an array of the range of x and y, with an optional step argument
var range = function(x, y, step){
    if (step == null) step = 1;

    // why do you call this variable arr? 
    // It's better to use a meaningful name like result.
    var arr = [];

    // what happens when y is less than x?
    // what happens when step equals zero?

    if (step > 0) {
        for (var i = x; i <= y; i += step)
            arr.push(i);
    } else {
        for (var i = x; i >= y; i += step)
            arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
};

// rangeSum(start,end) gives the sum of the range from start to end. 
// why do you use other argument names than in the range function?
// it's better to use consistent names.
// By the way: the names of these argument are better than the arguments
// of the range function, so I'd change those to start and end.         
var rangeSum = function(start,end){

    // why so complex? You can iterate over the range once and keep a running total.

    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) 
        arr.push(i);
    return arr.reduce(function(a,b){
        return a + b;   
    });
};
```

Comment: Good points and nice way to help me learn on my own. Thanks for your review and exercise! :)

Comment: Hey, I just finished going over your points and redoing the code. It really helped me to get a better understanding of everything. Your comments led me to using the MDN to find new operators/methods/syntax, etc. You can see the code as I've updated it thanks to you here: https://github.com/agraymd/beginnerMathFunctions/blob/master/beginnerMathFunctions.js I figure it isn't worth making a new question. I know theres still more ways I can improve the code to accept more input and stuff, but I'm not trying to reinvent a calculator. Just learn. So thanks again. Much better than when I started!